# Target excess whitespaces but keep new lines

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to clean some strings during a database migration and remove excess white spaces.

```
    An example of a string would be like this
          and for some reason has empty spaces
                in the beginning of new lines.
```

Sometimes only 1 empty space in beginning of new line.

I need to conserve space between words and new lines.

I've tried the following:

$string = str_replace('  ', ' ', $string); (only replaces some, not enough)

$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);  (removes line breaks)

The closest thing I came up with is this monstrocity:

```
        $string = str_replace('    ', ' ', $string);
        $string = str_replace('   ', ' ', $string);
        $string = str_replace('  ', ' ', $string);
        $string = str_replace('  ', ' ', $string);
        $string = str_replace(' ', ' ', $string);
        $string = str_replace(' ', ' ', $string);
        $string = str_replace('\r ', '\r', $string);
        $string = str_replace('\n ', '\n', $string);
```

it removes most white spaces, keeps new lines, but still manages to maintain that 1 annoying extra space at the beginning of new line.

What's the best way to do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an alternation to match either from the start of the line 1+ horizontal whitespace characters or between words keep 1 horizontal whitespace character and match those which are following.

Then replace with a empty string.

`^\h+|\h\K\h+`

**Explanation**

- `^\h+` Assert the start of the string and match one or more times a horizontal whitespace character
- `|` Or
- `\h\K\h+` Match a horizontal whitespace character, forget what was matched and then match one or more times a horizontal whitespace character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tL1lVu/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/CUD1j)

If you only want to match from the start of the string  you could use `^\h+`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
preg_replace('/\s+/S', " ", $string);
```

That should replace all multiple white-spaces, tabs and new-lines with just one.

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't conserve the break lines

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[ ]+/', ' ', $string);
```

It should replace multiple Spaces (not other white Space like newlines) with a single Space.

**Edit**:

If you need to remove Spaces from start of line, you can run the `preg_replace` Again with this pattern:

```
  $string = preg_replace('/^[ ]+/m', '', $string);
```

That will search for one or more Spaces at the start of line, replacing with an empty string.

Comment: Thank you, this is basically doing the same thing I'm doing in an elegant way! Do you know how I could also make it target that one single space that appears after a breakline?